# How do I set the height for a custom UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, height

I will be using a dynamic number of cells and resizing the height of the table on that basis. I could work out how to do this myself by I can't seem to resize the table. Whether I use 100 cells or 10 the view is set at the same height.

```
class generalTableViewController: UITableViewController {


    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        // self.tableView.contentSize.height = 2000
        // self.tableView.frame.size.height = 2000
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1000
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: use -: heightForRowAtIndexPath method of tableView

Comment: Are you trying to set the `UITableViewCell` height? or the `UITableView` height?

Comment: I can adjust the UITableViewCell, it's the UITableView I'm having trouble with.

Answer (score 1):

UITableViewControllers generally take over the entire view. To occupy only a portion of the view with a UITableView use a UIViewController.

> You should use a UIViewController subclass rather than a subclass of UITableViewController to manage a table view if the view to be managed is composed of multiple subviews, only one of which is a table view. The default behavior of the UITableViewController class is to make the table view fill the screen between the navigation bar and the tab bar (if either are present).

See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewAndDataModel/TableViewAndDataModel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH5-SW1) for Apple guidance. You basically just need to take care of some of the things the controller would normally handle for you.

Comment: I attempted to use the UIViewController but it I still can't get around the height limit. I might be using the wrong terminology. It is when I scroll, if I have say 1000 rows it only allows me to scroll a fixed distanced so I can never get beyond that if I have more rows.